Not provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found (not Spring Boot!)
I'm trying to migrate a JavaX.mail class to use Jakarta mail, as it's required to move from Tomcat 9 to 10. I'm receiving a message java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found when attempting to send emails via gmail.
I have included angus mail in the .classpath file, as well as the jakarta mail and activation
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/astump/src/codex/Java/asWeb/web/WEB-INF/lib/angus-mail-2.0.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/astump/src/codex/Java/asWeb/web/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/astump/src/codex/Java/asWeb/web/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.jakartaee-api-10.0.0.jar"/>

<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/astump/src/codex/Java/asWeb/web/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.mail-2.1.3.jar"/>

However, this is not resolving the issue.
I'm referencing Jakarta in my class via the following:
import jakarta.mail.Message;
import jakarta.mail.MessagingException;
import jakarta.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import jakarta.mail.Session;
import jakarta.mail.Transport;
import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import jakarta.activation.DataHandler;
import jakarta.activation.DataSource;
import jakarta.activation.FileDataSource;
import jakarta.mail.BodyPart;
import jakarta.mail.Folder;
import jakarta.mail.Multipart;
import jakarta.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import jakarta.mail.Store;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

Attempting  to change these imports to com.eclipse.angus.mail.Store, etc... did not work.

[edit] the question to add the code that uses these packages and jars.

Referring to the Eclipse-specific .classpath file is strange. You're not supposed to manually edit it. Having the jakarta.jakartaee-api-10.0.0.jar file there is also alarming. Take a step back. Do you actually know how to correctly build a WAR for Tomcat instead of a normal JEE server? Which build tool exactly are you using? If it's actually Maven, start here: stackoverflow.com/a/65703840

Angus mail and activation and jakarta mail and activation are all required
